# Evaluating string inside closure in groovy

Tags: groovy, closures, eval

```
sql.eachRow( query ) { columns ->
    println columns.firstname      //executes well
    Eval.me( "columns.firstname" ) //No such property: columns
}
```

How do I evaluate the String containing the closure variable `columns`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [3 parameter form](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html#me%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) of `Eval.me`:

```
Eval.me( 'columns', columns, 'columns.firstname' )
```